# C read/write to file - Access Violation

Tags: c, visual-studio, text-files, access-violation

I am trying to read and write simple Infix and Postfix expressions to a from a file. When the program reaches the lines where fgets is called, an Access Violation error pops up.

**Code**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header3.h"

char inFx[100], postFx[100];

int main() {
        FILE *fp = fopen_s(&fp, "input.txt", "r");
        remove("output.txt");
        FILE *fp2 = fopen_s(&fp2, "output.txt", "a");
        if (fp == 0)
        {
            printf("Could not open file\n");
        }
        else
        {
            int i = 0;

            while (fgets(inFx, sizeof(inFx), fp)) {  //access violation during runtime here
                size_t ln = strlen(inFx);
                int n = expEvaluate(inFx, ln, postFx); //refers to other class 
                if (inFx[ln] == '\n')
                   inFx[ln] = '\0';
                if (fp2 == 0)
                {
                    printf("Could not open file\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    while (*(postFx + i) != 0)
                    {
                        fputc(*(postFx + i++), fp2);
                    }
                    fputc('\n', fp2);
                }
            }
        }

        fclose(fp2);
        fclose(fp);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the definition of fopen_s, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx

Comment: OS/administration related, not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

`fopen_s()` returns an error code, NOT the file handle (that is assigned to the first parameter).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sure, look at your line: `FILE *fp = fopen_s(&fp, "input.txt", "r");` - it assigns whatever the function returns to your `fp` variable; the problem is - this function returns the error code. See MSDN link posted above by J.J. Hakala. The bottom line is - your `fp` variable is NOT a valid FILE pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You should not get the result of `fopen_s` into your FILE pointers.
Also, you should put your test on `fp2` before your loop. If you cannot open the File, then you will read your whole file `fp` but you won't do anything.

Comment: When you do `fopen_s(&fp, "input.txt", "r")` it initializes your `fp` pointer. So you don't have to do `fp = fopen_s(...)` because this will erase values in `fp` and you won't be able to use it. `fopen_s` returns an `errno_t` type, not a `FILE*` type.